# Getting the information of applications that are on notification bar

Tags: android

I'm doing an app that opens whatever applications that show up on status bar so that I can easily view one and go to next one, without having to press every notifications to go to each app. Is there any way I can get the list of apps that are on status bar, or is it not possible at all?  Sorry if this has already been covered here and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Latest OS version 4.3 introduced this capability in the API. Check out [NotificationListenerService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService.html).

[Feature update notes](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.3.html#NotificationListener).